# ASP.NET MVC 4 Authentication does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I am developing a website using ASP.NET MVC4. I have 2 different types of users. "UserA" and "UserB".

I also want each one of them, to go to their personal webpage, and I thought to add a redirect when they login.

Therefore, at the login function at the accountController.cs, I modified the login function as below

```
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {
               if (User.IsInRole("RoleA")){
                    return Redirect("/Home/RoleA")
}
               else if (User.IsInRole("RoleB"))
               {
                   return Redirect("/Home/RoleB");
               }

                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }
```

However, it enters the if, and it says that the user is not authenticated. Therefore, the

```
   if (User.IsInRole("RoleA")){
```

is wrong, although the user is "RoleA".

Why my user is not authenticated, and not redirected at his personal website?
If I comment my code, then the authentication works perfectly, and the user is redirected to the index.

EDIT:

I do not know if they are doing the same job, but I used

```
"Roles.GetRolesForUser("sergey").Contains("Developer")"
```

and I solved my problem. I hope without any security or operational holes

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx. The forms-authentication ticket supplies forms-authentication information to the ''next'' request made by the browser.

Here is another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647942/websecurity-currentusername-and-user-identity-name-are-null-after-logging-in) that details the particular problem you are experiencing.